# Add HTML attribute in Laravel Datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, laravel-5.4

I need `ID` attribute in HTML table of Laravel Datatable (https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) like below.

[image]

I am using Laravel 5.4 and Datatable 7.x. I am using AdminLTE also. My controller is like below. I need the `ID` attribute.

**UsersController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Validator;
use Datatables;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Users;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }    
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('adminlte::users');
    }    
    /**
     * return data for dashboard.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function get_users()
    {
        $users = Users::select(['id','name', 'user_name', 'email',]);

        return Datatables::of($users)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($users) {
                return '<button class="edit-modal btn btn-xs btn-primary">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
                        </button>';
            })
            ->make(true);
    }    
}
```

My JavaScript code is like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Display datatable
    $(function() {
        $('#users').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('get_users') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I get the output ?

Comment: I m not clear what u mean but is that what u want?
https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/row-options#row-id

Comment: Thanks for your reply @YeLwinSoe. This one is working for me `->setRowId('id')`. Thanks

Comment: glad it helps u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one

```
return Datatables::of($posts)
         ->setRowId('post_id')
         ->make(true);
```

Ref: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/row-options#row-id